# Adding a dataframe column of a lookup matching multiple columns, but not a merge / join

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Simplified dfs:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [6, 2, 4],
        "ID2": [2, 3, 4],
        "foo": [2, 3, 4],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [6, 2, 4],
        "ID2": [1, 3, 2],
        "foo": [2, 3, 4],
        "to_ignore": ["idk", "bar", "whatever"],
        "A": ["unwanted str", "desired str", "unwanted str"],
    }
)
```

We want to add a column to `df` which has values from `df2`'s `A` column where values from columns `ID` and `ID2` match like so:

```
   ID  ID2       NewCol
0   6    2          NaN
1   2    3  desired str
2   4    4          NaN
```

We can do this where one column's values match:

```py
df["NewCol"] = df["ID"].map(df2.drop_duplicates("ID").set_index("ID")["A"])
```

How can we make this only work for entries where both `ID` and `ID2` match? `df["NewCol"] = df["ID", "ID2"].map(df2.drop_duplicates("ID").set_index(["ID", "ID2"])["A"])` obviously doesn't work.

We could concatenate the ID cols and crudely use this above approach while risking concatenated ID strs incorrectly matching:

```py
for d in [df, df2]:
    d['lookup_combined'] = d["ID"] + d["ID2"]

df["NewCol"] = df["lookup_combined"].map(df2.drop_duplicates("lookup_combined").set_index("lookup_combined")["A"])

for d in [df, df2]:
    d.drop(columns="lookup_combined", inplace=True)
```

But this is clunky and error prone. Can we do better?

Note we don't want to merge / join the tables as there are more columns and other complications removed for question simplicity. We only want a new column named by a string we supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the function [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). You just need to indicate the columns on which you are merging on as follows:

```
df.merge(df2, how='left', on = ['ID', 'ID2'])
 
   ID  ID2            A
0   6    2          NaN
1   2    3  desired str
2   4    4          NaN
```

### Edit:

I still do not see where `merge` is an issue: with new data, just do:

```
vars = ['ID', 'ID2']
df[vars].merge(df2[vars + ['A']], how='left', on =vars)

   ID  ID2            A
0   6    2          NaN
1   2    3  desired str
2   4    4          NaN
```

Comment: Please see last paragraph. We don't want merge because of other complications removed for question simplicity.

Comment: @ChrisDixon You can only select the two columns from both tables merge them then concatenate to the full data with many columns. Also note that merging on these two columns will not in any way impacte the other columns and therefore there are no complications that can make you not merge the two datasets. You would need more than a mere statement to disaprove merging

Comment: OK, I've expanded on the eg to demonstrate merge complications.

Comment: @ChrisDixon where does the code fail? ie `vars = ['ID', 'ID2'];df[vars].merge(df2[vars], how='left', on =vars)`. Check the edit

Comment: This is nearly perfect but the result doesn't include the `foo` column. Why did you make `df[vars]` instead of `df`? Removing it seems to resolve that but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @ChrisDixon you claimed that the other columns complicated the issue. Also your output does not contain foo column. So removed it